# Image to fit grid cell size in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, grid

I have a grid with 2 rows and 2 columns.
At 0,0 I have a TextBlock with some text that can change due to localization, at 1,0 I have an Image.

Here is the example XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Tb" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Foobar</TextBlock>
        <Image Source="Foobar.jpg" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The size of the image used as the source for the Image element is unknown.

I need the grid column #0 to be as wide as the TextBlock text. The image should be as wide as the column, and its height should be set properly to keep the aspect ratio.

I tried wrapping the image in a [NoSizeDecorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854079/make-wpf-sl-grid-ignore-a-child-element-when-determining-size) but that way the image does not appear at all, unless I specify the image absolute height and width in the XAML, which I cannot do as I need the image the same width of the text.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code *should* already do what you want, with the addition of the `Image.Width` property:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Tb" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Foobar</TextBlock>
    <Image Source="Foobar.jpg" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Tb}" />
</Grid>
```

Here we are basically setting the `Image.Width` property from the `TextBlock.ActualWidth` to ensure that the `Image` does not grow too large. There is no need to use an expensive `ViewBox` control to do this.

Comment: +1, but please note that `Stretch="Uniform"` is the default value, so there is no need to set it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens (once again)... I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually already tried with the Width<-Tb.ActualWidth binding but probably had messed with some other attribute and could not get it to work.. Now it works, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do this without using a Grid. As my button has a Padding, I created a Border and bound to the Border's ActualWidth.

```
<Button Width="40" Height="40" Padding="3">
   <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      <Image Source="{StaticResource DoubleArrows}" 
             Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}"/>
   </Border>
</Button>
```