# Scale an image to its proper size but with a maximum width/heigth

Tags: wpf, grid

We have an image that needs to be shown as a splash screen. This image should be displayed in its actual size unless the width or height passes a certain maximum. In that case the image should be scaled to fit the window.

What we currently have is working fine except when the `MaxWidth` (or `MaxHeight`) is exceeded. In that case it just cuts of the image instead of scaling it.

I found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698361/image-to-fit-grid-cell-size-in-wpf) but it's not exactly the same. Is there a way to overcome this?

```
[XML]$Xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
    xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' x:Name='Window'
    WindowStartupLocation='CenterScreen' ResizeMode='NoResize'
    SizeToContent='WidthAndHeight' MaxWidth='600' MaxHeight='400'
    Title='Splash' WindowStyle='None'
>

<Grid>
    <!-- Use a grid with auto height and width to set the window to the size of the image -->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Use a grid in the button to set the size of the counter and the pause/resume label -->
    <Image Source='$Path'/>
    <Button Name='TimerButton' VerticalAlignment='Top' HorizontalAlignment='Right' Margin='0,3,3,0'>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="26"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name='ResumePauseLabel' Padding='0' HorizontalContentAlignment='Left' Content='II'/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name='TimerLabel' Padding='0' HorizontalContentAlignment='Center' Content='$Seconds'/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
```

Even when trying this, the image is still getting cut off:

```
<Image Source='$Path' Stretch='None' MaxHeight='400' MaxWidth='1800'/>
```

Final solution thanks to the comments of @mm8 and @Clemens was a change in the `Grid` and setting extra properties for the image:

```
        [XML]$Xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
    xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' x:Name='Window'
    WindowStartupLocation='CenterScreen' ResizeMode='NoResize'
    SizeToContent='WidthAndHeight' MaxWidth='1600 ' MaxHeight='1600'
>

<Grid>
        <Image Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly"  Source='$Path'/>
    <Button Name='TimerButton' VerticalAlignment='Top' HorizontalAlignment='Right' Margin='0,3,3,0'>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="26"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name='ResumePauseLabel' Padding='0' HorizontalContentAlignment='Left' Content='II'/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name='TimerLabel' Padding='0' HorizontalContentAlignment='Center' Content='$Seconds'/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `ViewBox`?

Comment: No, I'm quite a newbie in `wpf` and started with a `StackPanel` and now we're at a `Grid`.

Comment: Wrap the image in a `ViewBox` and place that in the `Grid`.So Grid->ViewBox->Image

Comment: When I try `<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"><Image Source='$Path'/></Viewbox>` in the `Grid` it's still cutting of the image

Comment: Have you set the MaxWidth and MaxHeight on the ViewBox?

Comment: And also there are more options to choose from for `Stretch`  [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.stretch?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @DarkLite1: Remove the `RowDefinition` and the `ColumnDefinition` of the outer `Grid` or set the `Height` and `Width` to `*` instead of `Auto`.

Comment: @mm8 if I then set `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth` to `1600` it scales over the original size of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Uniform` stretching with `StretchDirection` set to `DownOnly`.

The Image will be stretched to the layout bounds imposed by its parent Panel, but never grow larger than its native size.

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly" .../>
```

Comment: Make sure the parent Panel does proper layout, i.e. sets a maximum size.

Comment: Finally it works! It was a combination of your answer with `<RowDefinition Height="*"/> <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>` instead of `Auto` or just removing that part completely

Comment: Sure, Auto means the cell width or height gets the native size of the element in the cell.